# How is it proved that any maximal ideal in $K[X,Y]$ has only $2$ generators?

Tags: polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I would like to prove that any maximal ideal in $K[X,Y]$ has only $2$ generators, where $K$ is a field. My line for proof is shown below.

Let $I$ be a maximal ideal in $K[X,Y]$.

I took $I \cap K[X]$, which is an ideal in $K[X]$. Because $K[X]$ is PID, there is the polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$ such that $I \cap K[X]=(f(X))$. Similarly, I could take $g(Y) \in K[Y]$ such that $I \cap K[Y]=(g(Y))$. If I can prove that $I=(f(X),g(Y))$, then proof is done. However, I can't.

In addition, I took a polynomial $f_0(Y) \in I$ with the minimum degree in $Y$ and tried to use this polynomial for the proof, but it didn't go well.

Would you tell me any hints or ideas for this proof?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know an answer off the top of my head -- but for a counterexample to the proposed approach, consider the ideal $\langle X^2 + 1, Y - X \rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]$.  Your approach would get $f(X) = X^2 + 1$, $g(Y) = Y^2 + 1$; but $\langle X^2 + 1, Y^2 + 1 \rangle$ is not maximal because it's strictly contained in $\langle X^2 + 1, Y - X \rangle$.

Comment: That does suggest the approach of taking a generator of $I \cap K[X]$ as you started out with; but then, show that's maximal in $K[X]$, so $K[X] / \langle f(X) \rangle$ is a field, and you can consider $I$ as inducing an ideal of $(K[X] / \langle f(X) \rangle) [Y]$ which has a single generator.  I'm not immediately sure whether that will lead to a solution.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler Thank you for your helpful comment! I have understood that your line can go well.